# Accidentally installed ubuntu over Windows 7 now reinstalling Windows won't boot

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I am quite new to Linux Ubuntu and had installed it as a dual boot with my Windows 7.  I then tried to reinstall the ubuntu partition and accidentally wiped Windows.  Now i have tried to reinstall and start from a clean state with my Acer recovery discs and it appears to install normally but when it restarts it says:

```
Media test failure chceck cable
Exiting Broadcom PXE Rom
error:unknown fileystem
Entering resuce mode then grub rescue prompt
```

and I can't go into Windows 7 repair and command prompt as a lot of people seem to recommend because it isn't an option as far as I can see on the Acer recovery setup
how can I get back to my windows installation as per factory install?

Comment: Take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on. Hope you have your Windows Recovery CD to boot from it?

Comment: You need to repair your MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Linux / Ubuntu replaces the windows bootloader with its own grub, you will need to reinstall the windows bootloader. To do so you will need a windows install cd/dvd/usb

> Boot the Windows media
>   Click on Repair your computer (lower left corner)
>   Open command prompt there
>   Type this command: BootRec.exe /fixmbr

This should fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is setup to try to boot from the network first. That is what those 1st 2 lines mean. It doesn't work because it can't find a PXE boot-server on the network.

Then it attempts to boot from the harddisk.
It finds the Ubuntu boot-loader called GRUB (which wasn't removed by the Acer recovery), but the Acer recovery nuked the rest of the Ubuntu filesystem and that is what gives the next error.

If you have a Windows installation boot-media (USB or CD) available you can boot from that and attempt a boot-repair from that. That usually fixes this issue by over-writng GRUB with Windows bootloader.
I see Simon just posted an answer with the instructions for that.

Alternatively:
Before you run the Acer recovery (again) you should completely wipe the original harddisk, including the GRUB bootloader.
That should enable the Acer recovery to put the system back into the factory-default installation.
(And it still may be necessary to do the boot-loader repair using a Windows install disk.)